# vba code to insert file into table based on ID

Tags: ms-access

I have developed code which inserts files into an attachment field in an access database table.
The Table is called "Reports" and the attachment field is called "Field1". At the moment my code inserts files to the first record in the table "Reports", what i would like to do is add an attachment to a record based on its ID, So for example (add attachment to Field1 where the ID = some value) . Is this possible  can anyone help me out with this ?

```
Instantiate the parent recordset.
Set rsfile = db.OpenRecordset("Reports")


 Do While Not rsfile.EOF
If rsfile.Fields("ID").Value = 1 Then
' Activate edit mode.
rsfile.Edit

' Instantiate the child recordset.
Set rsReport = rsfile.Fields("Field1").Value

'Add a new attachment.
filePath = "C:\dbPDF\sitereport.pdf"
rsReport.AddNew
rsReport.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile (filePath)
rsReport.Update

' Update the parent record
rsfile.Update

rsfile.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate thought reports and update if condition match, is should be similar to this:

```
rsfile = db.OpenRecordset("Reports")

Do While Not rsfile.EOF
 If rsfile.Fields("ID").Value = 1 Then
    'Activate edit mode.
    rsfile.Edit

    'Instantiate the child recordset.
    Set rsReport = rsfile.Fields("Field1").Value
    'Add a new attachment.
    filePath = "C:\dbPDF\sitereport.pdf"
    rsReport.AddNew
    rsReport.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile (filePath)
    rsReport.Update 
    'Update the parent record
    rsfile.Update
 End If
'Next row
 rsfile.moveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Hi Wawrzyniec Sz that would work for me , how could i incorpate that into my code i have tried but get an error ?

Comment: i edited my code above adding your code into it , but get an error "loop with Do"

Comment: I have missed 'end if'. Corrected.

Comment: i try it out again and get back to you

Comment: Hi Wawrzyniec sorry in the delay in getting back to you , no joy i have tried adding your code different ways but always get an error "object invalid or no longer set". any ideas be great if i could get this working

Comment: the code i tried : Do While Not rsfile.EOF
    If rsfile.Fields("ID").Value = 1  then  
    'Do the update

 ' Activate edit mode.
   rsfile.Edit
   
   ' Instantiate the child recordset.
  
   Set rsReport = rsfile.Fields("Field1").Value
   
 
   'Add a new attachment.
   filePath = "C:\dbPDF\sitereport.pdf"
   rsReport.AddNew
   rsReport.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile (filePath)
   rsReport.Update
   
   ' Update the parent record
   rsfile.Update


    End If

    'Next row
     rsfile.moveNext
Loop

Comment: Got it working when i used your code , very happy to get this working now, thanks for all your help